# Переход курсора на другой input

Tags: angularjs

Имеется страница, на которой пользователь вводит ряд данных через input text. например, так:

```
<input type='text' id='input_1'>
<input type='text' id='input_2'>
```

с каждым input'ом связана отдельная модель (ngModel), например jump_1, jump_2. данные в модели представляют собой строку с максимальной длиной.

каждый input должен иметь определённую максимальную длину (например, 4). при достижении максимальной длины в input_1 фокус должен автоматически переместиться на input_2. Соответственно, если фокус находится на input_2, при удалении первого и единственного символа в этом инпуте фокус должен автоматически переместиться на input_1.

пробую написать директиву, что-то вроде такого:

```
app.directive('jumpInput', function() {
    return function($scope, element, attrs) {        
            $scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel,function(value){            
                    if (value.length>5)
                {angular.element("#" + attrs.jumpInput).focus();}
            });
        }
    });
```

HTML при этом выглядит примерно так:

```
<input type='text' id='jump_1' name="jump_1" ng-model='jump1' ng-maxlength="4" jump-input="jump_2">
<input type='text' id='jump_2' name="jump_2" ng-model='jump2' ng-maxlength="4">
```

но как-то оно не работает. Самый главный момент - не совсем понятно, как всё это соответствует MVC. По идее, вся логика должна помещаться в контроллере, который вообще ничего не должен знать о каких-то тегах, он работает только с моделями. Возможные решения вроде document.getElementByID выглядят как-то некрасиво.

Comment: что за несколько инпутов? откуда они берутся? как определяется очередность? значения из этих инпутов складываются в одну переменную или у каждого свое? если в одну, то какое у нее должно быть значение?

Comment: для каждого инпута своя переменная string. xxxxxxxx. если описывать в терминах MVC'шных моделей, например {{model1}} и {{model2}}. инпуты описаны в html по очереди. соответственно, переход курсора осуществляется в том порядке, в каком они идут в html.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
              if($(this).val().match(/^\d{8}$/)){
                   $(this).next('input').focus();
              }
              if ((e.keyCode==8 || e.keyCode == 46) && ($(this).val()=="")) {
                    $(this).prev('input').focus();
              }
});
```

Если срабатывает регулярка на 8 цифр, то переходим к следующему полю input. Если нажата клавиша Backspace (keycode = 8) или Delete (keycode = 46), то проверяем что символов в поле нет и переходим к предыдущему полю input.

Comment: но это jQuery, не Ангуляр. я вот не уверен, насколько это соответствует MVC